# Texture coordinates from world position

Tags: c++, directx11

Im making an editor in which I want to build a terrain map. I want to use my mouse to increase/decrease terrain altitude to create mountains and lakes essentially.

Technically I have a heightmap I want to modify at a certain texcoord that I pick out with my mouse. To do this I first go from screen coordinates to world position - I have done that. The next step going from world position to picking the right texture coordinate puzzles me though. How do I do that?

Comment: how does the texture coordinate relate to changing the height of your terrain?

Comment: It is the texcoord on the heightmap. So if I want to raise/lower terrain I must pick the right texel on the heightmap and modify that